# Why don't airlines load their passengers like freight?

Tags: airliner, commercial-aviation, passenger, economics, boarding

Apparently, the time for boarding and deboarding an airplane is a large cost factor and something airlines try to minimize but have trouble controlling because the passengers do it themselves.
A solution would be to have passengers board a passenger cabin outside of the airplane and then slide that cabin into the plane via a nose-hatch, much like large volume freight. Has this been considered? If yes, why was it not pursued?

Comment: Do you really want to treat passengers like cattle?

Comment: `Why don't airlines load their passengers like freight?`  You obviously haven't flown on some of the airlines I have,

Comment: Where would said cabin(s) physically be located? The logistical expense would seem just as large. Also more time without a lavatory.

Comment: They are called "self-loading cargo" for a reason. Your solution of a flatbed Jumbo would make pressurization harder and reduce payload substantially.

Comment: Passengers tend to object to being packed into cargo bins and left sitting upside down by inattentive ground handlers...

Comment: All the mentioned issues aside, how would you suggest to implement emergency exits in such a scenario?

Comment: Or physical access between cockpit and cabin? (Yes, it's sometimes needed! If for no other reason then because the pilots probably want to get in there somehow so they can do their job. You aren't proposing that they should be climbing in through the side windows, are you? :-))

Comment: When I read your Title, I thought to myself, "He couldn't really expect us to be loaded onto a plane by a Forklift, could he?" But then I read your question, and it sounds a little better now.

Comment: So you want people packed in like sardines even SOONER? Have you ever flown with kids? This sounds like a nightmare!

Comment: @corsiKa Those kids would be much *less* of a nightmare if jammed tightly together and packed in a tomato sauce.

Comment: @Simon, I signed up to A.SE just to upvote your comment.

Comment: I'd be very willing to travel in a '[capsule hotel](http://topoops.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/capsule-hotel-3.jpg)' type unit if it were the same price as an economy seat, because I'd get to lie down and go to sleep. I wouldn't at all mind it being stacked above/below other capsules. I would need to get out occasionally to go to the toilet though.

Comment: You can make it [more efficient](http://www.theonion.com/article/united-airlines-exploring-viability-of-stacking-th-2841) by dispensing with the cabins altogether!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Boarding takes a long time, true. There are [more efficient strategies (.pdf)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0733.pdf) which [have been proven](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5211) to speed up boarding by between 20% and 50%, still they are not adopted. Why?

You need to load the baggage, too. Also the catering. And fuel. You need to inspect the aircraft, run through checklists and brief the new crew. This all takes up time, too. Airlines do not see a big saving by loading passengers faster, and then waiting for all other jobs to be completed.

Your radical idea of containerizing passenger transport would certainly speed up things, but it would cost a lot of payload.

1. The most efficient pressure vessel is a sphere, and the next efficient is a cylinder with spherical ends. Pressurizing a boxy container is structurally very inefficient.
2. Loading passengers on palettes first and sliding those palettes through a narrow opening takes time in itself. And the palettes have their own weight, their own floor, their own support structure for the baggage racks, their own cabeling for the entertainment system. They would, however, not need their independent pressurization, so their weight impact would be moderate.
3. A possible "flatbed" airliner which could attain the shortest boarding times has only half as much fuselage height (or less) to transmit bending loads along its length. [See here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/why-does-the-757-fuselage-bend-more-on-turbulence-than-those-of-other-airplanes) for an example of buckling in a fuselage skin due to bending loads. Now consider that reducing height by 50% will need four times more cross section in the longerons to keep stiffness constant. That will make the fuselage much heavier.

In the end, airlines go with the solution which maximizes their profits. By using a hollow cylinder and let their "cargo" self-load, they can maximize their payload and get tolerable boarding times. Tolerable for them, that is. That better loading procedures could allow you to come to the airport later is of no interest to them. If they would see an advantage in shorter boarding times, there would be ample of opportunity by improving strategies, even with existing airplane designs.

Comment: I don't think it's certain that it *would* speed anything up. Loading a fuselage-sized container into a plane would be a slow, delicate job and I can imagine it taking rather longer than just getting 300 people through a door.

Comment: Plus, why would seating passengers into the removeable compartment be any quicker than seating passengers directly into the plane?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: When you have standard containers and let the aircraft taxi below two gantry cranes, one for taking the arriving container off and one for putting the departing container in place, the aircraft would be ready in a jiffy. I am sure by doing it cleverly that time can be saved.

Comment: @PeterKämpf this solution does not solve the problem of passenger who choose to do last minute shopping and arriving late at gate. I did that myself. It is more of a human factor that is limiting factor here.

Comment: @HorusKol The point isn't to speed up the loading time from the passenger's perspective, it's to speed it up from the aircraft's perspective. Aircraft are big expensive assets so the less "dead" time they have on the ground the better.  Speeding up turnaround times in general is a big win.

Comment: @PeterKämpf The question talks about sliding a capsule into the fuselage through a nose door, rather than piggybacking it on top of something. But I agree that the piggyback solution would give much faster loading.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You're right - the "hatch" term got me confused. And a Boeing concept from the Eighties of a "flatbed Jumbo". But the point is the same, nevertheless: The airlines don't see a need to speed up boarding.

Comment: "allow you to come to the airport later is of no interest to them" - that may depend on the distance travelled. The extra time spent at the airport has negative impact on being competitive with trains or cars over relatively short distances (though this lack of competitiveness may be seen as a global advantage with respect to ecology)

Comment: Let's face it. We humans, as evolved as we are, are still incapable accomplishing the simplest of tasks. Maybe you should have a big sign that reads "FREE FOOD AND DRINKS FOR THE NEXT 5 MINUTES ONLY!" at the other side of the entrance. I bet they'll move much quicker...

Comment: @NigelHarper but the plane would have to land near the loading area, remove the capsule, offload the passengers, onload new passengers, replace the capsule - unless you have a departing capsule ready on the ground to instantly replace the arriving one... but then you have issues of storage, and different size and types of planes coming in at quite high frequency in some airports

Comment: I had never heard of the Steffen method until a day or two ago, but I've always thought that's how planes should be loaded. It seems obvious that it's the optimal solution. It doesn't allow for priority boarding, though, which may be part of why it isn't done in practice. Those people up front always need to board first so everyone else on the plane can bang their baggage into them as they walk down the aisle, I guess. The Steffen method sure would be nice on very cold or very hot days rather than having everyone stand in the jetway because someone in row 3 is trying to shove in a bag.

Comment: @Peter Kämpf I wasn't necessarily thinking of loading a container, but rather a tray (i.e. only a floor with mounted seats and baggage holders) and sliding it into a slit in the inside of the -pressurized- fuselage, like into a tray holder.

Comment: @SebastianHenckel: Yes, I first got that wrong. What takes most time during boarding is people stuffing their oversized baggage into the overhead racks, blocking the aisle for everyone else. By sliding in trays with only seats, the stuffing part still needs to happen, with all the shuffling and waiting it involves. Wouldn't it be best to have that located outside the airplane? Then a fully seated compartment with all the carry-on baggage neatly stowed would be loaded in one go. That was my idea when I read the question first.

Comment: @HorusKol to be honest it didn't occur to me that anyone might think the question *didn't* contemplate having the "capsule" pre-loaded before the aircraft landed, since otherwise it would make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: *the next best shape would be a cylinder with spherical ends* I thought it would be an egg

Answer (score 18):

The system you propose would be extremely heavy compared to existing aircraft. More weight means more fuel and more fuel means even *more* fuel to carry that fuel through the air, and even more fuel to carry *that* fuel and so on.  Fuel is one of the biggest expenses an airline faces.

It would also be extremely expensive.  To gain any time, you'd have to have the departing passenger capsule loaded and ready before the arriving passengers have left their capsule. That means you need twice as many capsules as planes.

And the time saving wouldn't be all that great.  You'd still have to refuel the plane and load and unload the cargo.  Manoeuvring a fuselage-sized capsule into the plane would be a long job.  I'm far from convinced that it would be faster than getting however many hundred people through the door.

Comment: More to the point, maneuvering a fuselage-sized capsule *full of passengers* without jostling or injuring any of the occupants.

Comment: @Shadur If you were fully committed to the passengers-as-cargon idea, you wouldn't worry about jostling the cargo. ;-)

Comment: @Shadur -- well, don't forget, they have to do that with the plane as a whole.

Answer (score 7):

The first and biggest concern would be the weight of the container. They need to have walls, floor and a ceiling and be able to lock in place on the plane.

Also each division between containers would remove some room available for another row of seats in the traditional method.

Comment: Don't forget that the most efficient geometry for a pressure vessel is a sphere, followed by a cylinder with spherical ends. The boxy container is impossible to pressurize without substantial deformation.

Comment: @PeterKämpf which means that the pressurization must come from the fuselage still, I didn't forget that. It also means that the "nose-hatch" much be strong enough to withstand pressurization.

Comment: @ratchetfreak The nose hatch withstanding pressurization isn't a particularly intractable problem, though. [Such aircraft already exist](http://www.avsim.com/pages/0209/JustFlight/pic_05_01.jpg). I don't feel like doing the calculations right now, but it wouldn't surprise me at all if the pressure applied to the outside actually exceeds the pressure being applied from the inside on the front section of the aircraft (which is, obviously, facing the airstream.)

Answer (score 6):

Passenger crates were envisaged a long time ago. Apart from the above objections, may I add this: A passenger crate in a plane is a box in a box. This would worsen claustrophobia which is already a problem. A view outside would alleviate this, but requires windows. Crate windows would need to be aligned with fuselage portholes.

The psychological problem is doubled by a physical problem which is emergency evacuation.

Any project would need a highly standardised crate compatible with competing aircraft types. This standard would later become a constraint for future design innovation. It would also limit customisation of planes by constructors for specific customers.

Comment: Emergency evacuation is a *very* good point (eject the capsule!!! ;-). But I disagree on standardization, as I don't see why you'd need a standardized crate to get the benefit of a faster turnaround for the main plane. And surely it would *increase* customization? Most customization these days is in cabin layout but, in this scheme, the cabin is a completely separate module.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: To load passenger crates independent of aircraft type and position within the plane will need a lot of standardization: Everything needs to line up correctly, from air ducts to escape doors. Paul has a very valid point here.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yes, to do it independent of plane type would require standardization. But why would it need to be independent of plane type? For example, airports today cope just fine with loading Boeings and Airbuses of various different sizes. Why couldn't they load 777 capsules into 777s, A380 capsules into A380s, etc.? The problem seems to be with the capsule concept, not with different planes taking different capsules.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't want all of the connections for pressurisation, air conditioning, lighting, water, IFE etc etc connected and disconncted every flight.  A maintenance and safety headache.

Answer (score 2):

Something even more radical *has* been considered! Airbus [filed a patent on](http://arstechnica.co.uk/cars/2015/11/airbus-proposes-new-drop-in-airplane-cabin-modules-to-speed-up-boarding/) replacing the entire upper fuselage - seats, passengers and all - during a layover. The structural problems inherent in that idea look pretty hard though.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: "Has this been considered? If yes, why was it not pursued?" Okay, so it slides in from the top/side rather than through the nose, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that delays in loading passengers onto aeroplanes come from two sources:

1) Security & border concerns since the hijacking of aircraft became common in the 1970s;

2) Airports' desire to make money from passengers being forced to wait in airports, where they buy things from retailers who are paying tenants of the airport.

On the topic of (2) a British airport group (Heathrow is one of their properties) told shareholders around 15 years ago that they were not in the transport business, but in the retail business, pointing out that over 60% of their revenues came from rents paid by airport retailers.

It's elementary economics that while this is the case, airports and airlines have no incentive to make aircraft boarding quicker, even if a solution for (1) were found. Were airports to shift their revenue model away from retail, this entails airlines paying more for landing slots, so the two groups have a common interest in wasting the time of travellers by keeping them in airports for as long as possible out of their travel time.

A saner approach to speeding up the loading of passengers would be - rather than loading them in boxes like freight - to simply cut the airport out and have passengers board special buses in town, check their bags and travel documents with a couple of officials who are also travelling on the bus, and have those buses drive straight onto the tarmac and up to the aeroplane.

This is after all how very rich people travel. Someone drives them straight to the aeroplane.

Airports earning 60% of revenues from in-airport retail tenants are unlikely to support this simple idea, however.

Comment: This answer seems to be subjective with personal opinions. I also highly doubt if your "bus direct to terminal" solution is practical at all.

Comment: I don't think that this is what the question is about. Time lost in the airport does not cost the airline anything, it's the time spent by the aircraft on the ground that is a large cost factor. Your “solution” would actually be worse, from the airline's point of view.

Comment: I understand your point, Relaxed, that the question seeks to reduce aircraft loading times, though I'm not sure why bus-loading would be worse. Is it subjective, kevin, to consider who benefits commercially from the current status quo? And why would travellers loaded into a kind of pallet favour airports, since pallets could be transported from anywhere? I'd argue that the bus-to-the-aircraft solution must be _more_ practical: planes can park on a much larger area of tarmac away from buildings. Some airports take passengers to the plane in buses already, so why not drive buses out of town?

Comment: @MarkGriffith For one thing, busses in town are accessible by millions of people with no security controls at all. Therefore, to maintain the current level of security, they'd all have to be searched thoroughly before being allowed to enter the ramp. Keeping the entire aircraft in a secure area and just checking the bags and passengers is much more cost and time efficient.

Comment: Also, if airliners boarded faster, passengers would, on average, spend _more_ time in the terminal where they could be buying stuff, not less. Passengers can't be buying stuff while they're standing in line in the jetway waiting on the guy in row 3 to shove his bag in the overhead. If boarding took only 10 minutes instead of 20, for example, that's 10 minutes longer people can wait in the terminal before boarding where they could be buying stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I for one would jump at the chance to arrive earlier, "board" earlier and sit in cramped airline seating even longer so the airline can save money.

If you didn't pre-load the passengers in your capsules before the plane was ready to depart, there would be no time savings.

No thanks. It's bad enough they hold you prisoner on the plane when there are hour + long delays in departure.

Comment: That has nothing to do with boarding and everything to do with how pilots and air crew are paid. Basically less or not at all when the plane is hooked into up at the terminal. Pay starts when the door closes.