# Why is the shape of the cargo compartment similar in large aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design

Why are the lower deck areas shaped like that, does that save some space? I find it common across lot of big aircraft.

Pic of a 777:
[image: 777 Cargo Compartment]

Answer (score 19):

The answer lies in the existence of something called a [Unit Load Device (ULD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device) -- basically a cargo pod for aircraft that's the equivalent of the [shipping pallet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallet).
ULDs allow oddly-shaped cargo (bags, assorted-size boxes, etc.) to be loaded efficiently in a standard volume and easily secured for flight (using hold-down lugs in the floor).

The shape of the cargo deck is designed to pack in as many ULDs as possible:
[image: A300 cross-section with ULDs]
and as you can see from the cross-section the sloping sides on the bottom are a concession to the circular cross-section of the fuselage/pressure vessel.

Some other advantages of ULDs as they pertain to airline operations and baggage loading are described [over on this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/why-is-luggage-required-to-be-loaded-in-containers).

Comment: Why not expand the cargo compartment to use the whole bottom half?

Comment: There are a number of systems (e.g., power, flight controls, environmental ducts) routed through the spaces alongside & under the cargo area.

Comment: @immibis: Standardization. It's more economical to use a standard part for all aircraft than require each type of aircraft to use different containers. Conceivably, when ULDs were invented they use a higher % of the cross section of the average airliner. Nowdays widebodies are common so they end up using a smaller % of the cross-section.

Comment: @immibis I'm not sure what you mean by "the whole bottom half" -- are you saying just throw things into the bottom half-cylinder of the fuselage? If so, how will you accomplish the loading? (Hint: "Throw everything in there loose" doesn't work: It's inefficient in both space and time, and has other problems detailed in the post I linked to.) Similarly having half-cylinder ULDs doesn't work (they're too difficult to handle on the ground). ULDs trade a relatively small percentage of wasted space for enormous gains in cargo-handling efficiency.

Comment: @voretaq7 No. See the gap under the cargo bay in the photo, and the gaps to the sides - I meant expanding the cargo bay to use that space (and expanding the containers to fill the new cargo bay)

Comment: With airlines being cost-concious, I am sure they must be thinking of changing the design to accomodate more stuff... Good explanation none the less..

Comment: @immibis: The bottom surface holds rails for quick loading. That's intentionally a horizontal surface. The space to the side is fairly small.

Comment: Does anybody have a similar cross section image for the A320. Couldn't find anything good in google.